Laravel MorphMany: Avoiding N+1 Queries When Accessing MorphTo Relationship Attribute?
PHP: 8.2
Laravel Framework: 11
MySQL
We have roughly the following code on our website to represent the overall problem.
Post.php
class Post extends BaseModel
{
    public function blocks(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Block::class, 'blockable');
    }
}

Block.php
class Block extends Model
{
    public function blockable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function alt(): string
    {
        $alt = '';

        if ($this->caption) {
            $alt = $this->caption;
        } else if ($this->blockable->title) {
            $alt = 'Block from ' . $this->blockable->title;
        }

        return $alt;
    }
}

PostController.php
$posts = Post::where('status_id', 1)
    ->with('blocks')
    ->get();

This code works correctly and returns the expected result. But by calling $this->blockable within the alt function, it produces extra (duplicate) MySQL queries to find the parent, even though it is already queried and present. Is there a way to let Laravel know that blockable has already been queried as the parent?
One quick solution we found was the following, but we feel there is a more eloquent way of achieving this.
public function alt(Post $blockable): string
{
    $alt = '';

    if ($this->caption) {
        $alt = $this->caption;
    } else if ($blockable->title) {
        $alt = 'Block from ' . $blockable->title;
    }

    return $alt;
}


What do you mean when you say "it is already queried and present. Is there a way to let Laravel know that blockable has already been queried as the parent?" where is it already queried and present? Laravel does not have a type of "cache" saying that "if you already queried this data, don't query it again", you can use the relationship and it will be cached, but not query wise, so, just following the relationship, Laravel (Eloquent) has no idea it was already done before. You need to explain just a bit more, because if it is already present, you are wrongly getting info here, I think

@matiaslauriti thanks for your comment. So we load $posts->with('blocks'). So the posts and blocks are loaded together. So we have loaded $post->title already. But when we access $this->blockable->title which is the same as the already loaded $post->title. Instead of using $post->title Laravel runs a new query to get the same post record again, even though it's already loaded. On a page with 30 posts this is an extra 30 unnecessary queries.

There is no way to tell Eloquent that it was already loaded on another relationship, how does Eloquent know that? It is more complex to achieve, that would require you to do the right calls on the code

You're right, there may not be a solution here, and that's probably the point of the question. But the parent and the relationship are loaded at the same time in one object. So I feel like there is a better way to navigate the loaded object than doing a new query.

You should eager load the blockable relation like block realation.
$posts = Post::where('status_id', 1)
    ->with('blocks.blockable')
    ->get();

because you are using blockable here :


In that case, you can directly remove blocks as the first entry, it can just be blocks.blockable and it will still eager load blocks too

Thanks, we tried this, but I think it added an extra query to get blockable. Which was redundant because $post is already the blockable there is no reason to query the same object twice. I'll check it again, but I think our quick solution above produces less queries. But there has to be a better way to accomplish this.

Or even, why should we eager load blockable when we already have post, they are the same object.

@SnYpe I'm marking this as it best answers the question I put forward. I'm going to post another query which is more specific about lowering the number of queries.
